# Apache V Nginx - Static File Results

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

I used ab (ab -c50 -t5s) to benchmark Apache V Nginx for a static file on the same server.

Apache becomes CPU bound at 200 requests per second and Nginx is at about 25% CPU while handline 5211 requests per second.

No swapping took place with Apache, lack of memory wasn't an issue.

I know there are a myriad of different configurations for both Nginx and Apache, but how far behind Apache is Nginx is just ridiculous.

So ridiculous in fact that I think I've missed something with Apache.

Any ideas where to start?

Here are the ab results:

```
Server Software:        nginx  
Server Port:            80  

Document Path:          /images/15.jpg  
Document Length:        15088 bytes  

Concurrency Level:      50  
Time taken for tests:   5.494 seconds  
Complete requests:      26059  
Failed requests:        0  
Write errors:           0  
Total transferred:      400370476 bytes  
HTML transferred:       393178192 bytes  
Requests per second:    5211.29 [#/sec] (mean)  
Time per request:       9.595 [ms] (mean)  
Time per request:       0.192 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)  
Transfer rate:          78189.48 [Kbytes/sec] received  

Connection Times (ms)  
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max  
Connect:        0    4   0.6      4      10  
Processing:     3    5   0.8      5      13  
Waiting:        0    2   1.3      2      10  
Total:          6    9   0.9      9      19  

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)  
  50%      9  
  66%      9  
  75%      9  
  80%      9  
  90%     10  
  95%     10  
  98%     11  
  99%     12  
 100%     19 (longest request)  


Server Software:        Apache  
Server Port:            81  

Document Path:          /images/15.jpg  
Document Length:        15088 bytes  

Concurrency Level:      50  
Time taken for tests:   5.31551 seconds  
Complete requests:      1008  
Failed requests:        0  
Write errors:           0  
Total transferred:      15681815 bytes  
HTML transferred:       15433585 bytes  
Requests per second:    200.34 [#/sec] (mean)  
Time per request:       249.581 [ms] (mean)  
Time per request:       4.992 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)  
Transfer rate:          3043.59 [Kbytes/sec] received  

Connection Times (ms)  
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max  
Connect:        2   84  47.5     78     222  
Processing:    24  158  46.5    162     260  
Waiting:        1   96  45.1     91     221  
Total:        187  242  48.5    232     428  

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)  
  50%    232  
  66%    238  
  75%    246  
  80%    249  
  90%    304  
  95%    380  
  98%    409  
  99%    423  
 100%    428 (longest request)
```

Comment: Please share your config files for nginx and apache.

Comment: The thing is, `nginx` is *that* more powerful... So you may not have missed anything. `nginx` is highly optimized in a C well-written program.

Comment: The Apache config file is too large to post here. But I can say this, Nginx is the default install from the Atomic Rocket Turtle yum repository and Apache is the default install for Centos 5.5, 64 bit. I may not have missed anything, just thought I'd double check it wasn't something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

This post is now defunct.

I discovered that this is NOT a standard Apache setup and the extended mod_security rules is the issue.

Comment: Would you mind performing again the benchmarking without  the `mod_security` module?

Comment: There isn't enough room here for me to post the full results but I'm getting around 2000 requested per second without mod_security. Yes, literally 10 times the performance. I have subscribed to extensive mod_security rulesets and I have contacted the vendor about the performance. But it's clear, mod_security is limiting Apache's performance and making it CPU bound.

Comment: A 10x reduction in requests per second is not outlandish for mod_security with a big ruleset, this kind of deep HTTP inspection will cost you dearly on performance. You should not use mod_security on basic static file serving, this can be adequately secured by less intrusive means. Only run mod_security in front of a true web application.